# She and her sisters ____ our dog (adore) ...what should come here?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, spoken-english

Do we treat it as singular or plural? Will it be *adore* or *adores*?

Answer (score 2):

Plural: She and her sisters adore the dogs.

The same rule would apply even in a sentence like this one: The girls and their brother adore the dogs. Since "she and her sisters" are plural, and since "the girls and their brother" are plural, each verb must accommodate the plural subject regardless of whether the word immediately before the verb is "sisters," (which is plural) or "brother" (which is singular).

The word "or" works differently. If a sentence begins "She ***or*** her sisters," the verb is governed by "sisters" and is accordingly plural; but if a sentence begins "The girls ***or*** their brother," then the word "brother" governs the verb and it is singular. She or her sisters *are* at home. But the girls or their brother *is* upstairs.

(I believe that this is the formal rule, but it seems that lots of native speakers avoid a construction like that last one because it sounds unnatural to them.)